# submitHandler and .validate() issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

recently i had problem with attaching file into email, i handle that, thanks for you guys btw. Now i have next problem connected with "fixed" attching the file.
Actually there is more problems than i thought. 
1) in code below, in validation plugin, i thought that it's enought to call in rules somenthing like this "name : requred", but it isn't. To make it works i have to call in form class="required", why ? When i remove class="requred" validation is no longer exist.

2) Ok, so class="required", small problem, validation is working, but what happend with submitHandler ? ajax doesnt run, website refresh and i get succes message. My point is to send email with attachment without refreshig.

3) to make matters worse, the "message" that i wrote to uploaded_file rule, which should show when file is not uploaded, doesnt appear, insted the message from title attribute (in form) come into.

so everything is not that i was supposed to by. What shoud i repair/fix/change to make it work? please help me

the codes:
form:

```
 <form method="post" name="formularzaplikacyjny" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mail-attachment.php" id="formmail"> 

        <div id="imiediv"><label for="name">Imię i nazwisko: <em>*</em> </label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" title="Wpisz swoje imię i nazwisko" placeholder="Jan Kowalski"></div><br>

        <div id="emaildiv"><label for="email">Email: <em>*</em> </label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="required" id="email"  title="Wpisz swój adres email" placeholder="twoj_adres_email@email.com"></div><br>

        <div id="listdiv"><label for="message">List motywacyjny: <em>*</em></label><br>
                        <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="48" class="required" id="message" title="Wpisz treść listu motywacyjnego"  placeholder="Tutaj zpowinna znaleźć się treść Twojego listu motywacyjnego" ></textarea></div>

        <div id="cvdiv"><label for="uploaded_file">Wybierz plik CV: <em>*</em></label><br>
                        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" title="<h3>Wybierz plik CV do przesłania</h3>" class="required" id="uploaded_file"></div><br>

                        <input type="submit" value="Prześlij" name="submit" id="submitbutton">
                        </form>

                        <div id="loading-mail">
                            <h2>Wysyłamy maila.....</h2>
                          </div>
```

validation :

```
$("#formmail").validate({

   rules: {
     email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
     },
      name: {
        required: true

     }, 
     message: {
        required: true
     },
     uploaded_file: {
        requred: true
     }
   }, //koniec literału obiektowego rules
   messages: {
      email: {
         required: "<h3>Podaj adres e-mail.</h3>",
         email: "<h3>To nie jest prawidłowy <br>adres e-mail.</h3>"
       },
       name: {
         required: "<h3>Podaj swoje imię i nazwisko.</h3>"
       },
      message: {
        required: "<h3>Wpisz treść listu motywacyjnego.</h3>"
      },
      uploaded_file: {
        requred: "<h3>Prześlij plik CV</h3>"
     }
   },submitHandler: function() {


        var thisForm = $('#formmail');
        $('#formmail').fadeOut(function(){
          //Display the "loading" message
          $("#loading-mail").fadeIn(function(){
            //Post the form to the send script
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: thisForm.attr("action"),
              data: thisForm.serialize(),
              //Wait for a successful response
              success: function(data){
                //Hide the "loading" message
                $("#loading-mail").fadeOut(function(){
                  //Display the "success" message
                  $("#success").text(data).fadeIn();
                });
              }
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });  // koniec funkcji validate
```

and sending script:

```
<?php
require "PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php";



$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$bodys="<b>Podanie od:</b> ".$_POST['name']."<br/>"."<b>Adres e-mail: </b>".$_POST['email']."<br/>"."<b>Treść listu motywacyjnego: </b><br/>".$_POST['message'];
$mail->Body =$bodys; 

$mail->IsSMTP(); // tell the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port = 25; // set the SMTP server port
$mail->Host = "mail.xxx.linuxpl.info"; // SMTP server
$mail->Username = "username"; // SMTP server username
$mail->Password = "pass"; // SMTP server password

$mail->IsSendmail(); // tell the class to use Sendmail

$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);

$mail->From = $_POST['email']; //uzupełnij sobie
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name']; //uzupełnij sobie

$to = 'xxx@gmail.com'; //na jaki mail wysłać np ala@wp.pl



$mail->AddAddress($to);

$mail->Subject = "Nowe podanie o pracę";

$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap = 80; // set word wrap

$mail->MsgHTML($bodys);



$plik_tmp = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$plik_rozmiar = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
$plik_nazwa = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
if(is_uploaded_file($plik_tmp)) {   
$nazwa_g=$plik_nazwa;

move_uploaded_file($plik_tmp, 'tmp_zal/'.$nazwa_g); 
$mail->AddAttachment('tmp_zal/'.$nazwa_g, $nazwa_g);
}





$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML




if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Błąd";
echo "Kod błędu: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo 'Wiadomość została wysłana';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issues 1 & 3 are because you misspelled `required` as `requred` in the `uploaded_file` rule and message.

For issue 2 you need to `return false` from `submitHandler` to cancel the default form submission

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#formmail").validate({

        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            name: {
                required: true

            }, 
            message: {
                required: true
            },
            uploaded_file: {
                required: true
            }
        }, //koniec literału obiektowego rules
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "<h3>Podaj adres e-mail.</h3>",
                email: "<h3>To nie jest prawidłowy <br>adres e-mail.</h3>"
            },
            name: {
                required: "<h3>Podaj swoje imię i nazwisko.</h3>"
            },
            message: {
                required: "<h3>Wpisz treść listu motywacyjnego.</h3>"
            },
            uploaded_file: {
                required: "<h3>Prześlij plik CV</h3>"
            }
        },submitHandler: function() {


            var thisForm = $('#formmail');
            $('#formmail').fadeOut(function(){
                //Display the "loading" message
                $("#loading-mail").fadeIn(function(){
                    //Post the form to the send script
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: thisForm.attr("action"),
                        data: thisForm.serialize(),
                        //Wait for a successful response
                        success: function(data){
                            //Hide the "loading" message
                            $("#loading-mail").fadeOut(function(){
                                //Display the "success" message
                                $("#success").text(data).fadeIn();
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            return false
        }
    }); 
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fNvX9/)

**Note**: The ajax submission will not work because of the file input in the form - for some alternates see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928318/issues-with-jquery-validation-plugin-and-input-file/18928348#18928348)

Comment: ok, so i changed it into this:
.......},submitHandler: function() {
$('#formmail').fadeOut(function(){
$("#loading-mail").fadeIn(function(){
var form =document.getElementById('#formmail');
var formData = new FormData(form);

 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: form.attr("action"),
 data: formData,
 success: function(data){
 $("#loading-mail").fadeOut(function(){
 $("#success").text(data).fadeIn();
  });

and its still doesnt work, it stops when the loading message come into. Next nothing happens

Comment: yeeesss yeeessss damn it, it works, i add after "data" , sth like this: "processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType", and it works right now perfectly, thank you very much !

Comment: @user2760441 check this answer as correct if it is.