# jQuery validator not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am new to jQuery validator.

i am making WordPress site i am using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-password-validation/ plugin dor password validation.

jQuery validator not working and not showing any error .

i have been trying a lot not able to work it out.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4WdC/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upme-registration-form").validate({
        rules: {
            user_login: {
                required: true
            },
            user_email: {
                required: true
            },
            user_pass: {
                password: "#user_pass"
            },
            user_pass_confirm: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#user_pass_confirm"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            user_login: {
                required: "Enter a username",
                minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
            },
            user_email: {
                required: "Enter a username",
                minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
            },
            user_pass_confirm: {
                required: "Repeat your password",
                minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
                equalTo: "Enter the same password as above"
            }
        },
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.prependTo(element.parent().next());
        },
        // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert("submitted!");
        },
        // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
        success: function (label) {
            // set &nbsp; as text for IE
            label.html("&nbsp;HELLo").addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

i made this above code with the help of [submitHandler and .validate() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931457/submithandler-and-validate-issue/18931541#18931541) but not able to work

thank you

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. In the fiddle you have included the validate.password.js before validate.js, it is wrong as validate.password.js depends on validate.js - so you need to include the validate.js first
2. You are including a very old version of the validate plugin which had a dependency on jQuery browser which was [removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) - so either upgrade the library to new version of use jQuery 1.8.3 or use jQuery >= 1.9 with the [migration plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin)
3. The error placement function is not proper as the parent is the last item, so try `error.appendTo(element.parent());` instead.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R7xD7/)

Comment: @user2586839 you have not specified any validation rules in the site

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am testing it on my localhost. It's not working .

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah it's validating but not submitting. Please help .

Comment: @user2586839, if it's "not submitting", then why did you accept this answer?  Did you figure it out?  Were you simply mistaken and it's working now?  Please update us.

Comment: @Sparky I removed the submit and success handler to make it work.